# Need to remove ':' from the specific field value from json output

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, json.net

I am trying to remove the : from the specific field value from the json output.

Please find the json output:

```
{
    "suite_id": 111,
    "object_type": 2,
    "jobs": [
        {
            "jobId": 222,
            "creationTime": "2022-04-12T13:38:02Z",
            "browser": "chrome",
            "browserVersion": "",
            "platform": "win",
            "platform_version": "",
            "appiumVersion": "",
            "deviceName": "",
            "deviceOrientation": "",
            "isSerial": false,
            "totalExecutions": 1,
            "isRetryExecAvailable": false,
            "jobExecutionStatus": 1,
            "etrs": {
                "tasks": [
                    {
                        "executionId": 333,
                        "executionName": "Testing",
                        "executionStatus": "SUCCESS",
                        "restartExecutionStatus": "",
                        "restartExecutionId": 0,
                        "restartExecutionReportUrl": "",
                        "restartExecutionVideoUrl": "",
                        "initiatedOn": "2022-04-12T13:38:05Z",
                        "projectName": "Testproject",
                        "projectId": 1,
                        "executionVideoUrl": "",
                        "reportUrl": "avsfershd",
                        "testcaseId": 666,
                        "testCaseName": "testcase",
                        "errorsCount": 0,
                        "warningsCount": 0,
                        "statusMessage": "Success"
                    }
                ],
                "total_execs": 0
            },
            "environmentType": "local"
        }
]
}
```

I am taking the initiatedOn value from the json output by
$value = $Output.jobs.etrs.tasks.initiatedOn

which giving me value 2022-04-12T13:38:05Z but I need to remove : from the value.

Thank you,
Shivam

Comment: purely out of curiosity ... why do you need to remove those time delimiters?

Comment: I would not try and remove that. Just cast it to `[datetime]` and work with that object

Comment: `$value = $value -replace ':'`

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey, I need to use this value to create file and : delimiter is not valid in the file name.

Comment: Thank you so much @MathiasR.Jessen for the pointer.
Can we also just make the value only 2022-04-12 and remove rest value from it.

Comment: @ShivamSingh - thank you for the `why` of it. i was quite curious ... [*grin*]

Comment: If you just want the date you could use `$Output.jobs.etrs.tasks.initiatedOn.Substring(0,10)` or `$Output.jobs.etrs.tasks.initiatedOn.Split('T')[0]`.

Comment: Thank you @BaconBits :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment,

I would cast this [universal sortable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-universal-sortable-u-format-specifier)  date formatted string into a `[datetime]` object, which you can format as you like instead of cutting off part of the string..

```
$value = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f [datetime]$Output.jobs.etrs.tasks.initiatedOn
```

Your example ends with the `Z` for Zulu Time (UTC + 00:00), but another value may look like `2022-04-12T13:38:05+08:00`, so converting it to datetime would IMO be best.

Comment: Thank you @Theo :)

Comment: I would exercise caution doing it this way. You can potentially get unexpected date changes. For example, if you live in the western hemisphere `'{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f [datetime]"2022-04-12T00:38:05Z"` returns `2022-04-11` instead of `2022-04-12`. It may be correct, but it may not be. It entirely depends on what you're trying to accomplish. You may be able to correct it with `'{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f ([datetime]"2022-04-12T00:38:05Z").ToUniversalTime()`, but that may also be not what you want.

Comment: Thank you @BaconBits for such in depth information.